# How to refresh Lead page after Automatic conversion

Tags: apex, lightning-experience, leads, lead-conversion

I requirement is to auto convert lead when lead status = 'Qualified'.
I am using apex class and process builder.
Process Builder will call apex to Auto convert lead.
Conversion process works fine but the issue is lead page remains same. If I refresh the page it redirects to Converted Account.

For Example:
In Lightning Experience, I am updating Lead status to 'Qualified'. The lead got automatically converted to Account, contact and Opportunity. But the lead page didn't get refreshed. It remains the same. If I again refresh the page manually it goes to newly created Account.

Is ther any way to refresh this automatically once the lead got converted.

Answer (score 0):

IDK if this is the cleanest way but you could remove Lead.Status from your Lead Layout, then add Lead.Status to a visualforce page and embed the vf page in your Lead Layout. That would allow you to add a script to the vf page that calls a redirect method on your page’s controller whenever Lead.Status changes to Qualified. This assumes that you put your Lead  Conversion logic inside this controller too (before the redirect happens). I havent tested this but perhaps this helps you

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I am using only Apex class which will be called from Process Builder.

Comment: Regardless of whether you are using Classic or Lightning, it sounds like you are using a standard detail page layout. Generally-speaking Process Builder is for back-end automation (server-side logic) but it sounds like you need client-side redirecting, thus i believe your solution should be built on the page for the user.  Consider this and my original answer.  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks again for a solution. Why we used process builder is that we are doing some automation that needs to completed before automatic lead conversion starts. Is there any to redirect to convert account in the apex. We are not using Vf page

Comment: Although Process Builder helps you with some server-side logic, you are left without a page redirect.  You cannot issue a page redirect from Process Builder. You can from the apex setRedirect method in a visualforce controller.  You can achieve the same pre-conversion logic in apex as you can in Process Builder.  As you dont use lightning experience I am 85% confident that visualforce is your only option.  It is worth more research to be sure.  If you use visualforce maybe refer to this: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000l4LlQAI or to avoid coding try Visual Flow Buttons